# How to subtract one vector from another in Sketch?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

The mic is a series of strokes, and the circle is a drawn circle in sketch. I am trying to make the mic symbol transparent with the rest of the circle filled in. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the [boolean subtract operation](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/shapes/boolean-operations/) — I would highly recommend reading the linked page since it's a very valuable resource.

You might get some weirdness since the microphone shape is a set of paths rather than a combined shape of its own, but you can correct that with `Layer` > `Convert to Outlines` before using the subtract operation.